# Jerky scrolling when adding/removing views to ScrollView's child

Tags: android, scrollview

I hope someone can give an idea on how to improve the performance of the scrolling on my app.

Basically I have tiles/images being generated in a secondary thread, and once they are ready I add them to a RelativeLayout on a specific position with LayoutParams. For now I'm setting the size of this RelativeLayout as fixed to avoid complexities. This RelativeLayout is the one I add to the ScrollView.

I also listen for the scroll change event of the ScrollView, so I am able to request new tiles when I scroll to a new position. When this happens, new tiles are generated on the secondary thread, and at the same time I get the information to remove old tiles that are not necessary anymore (this helps to keep the quantity of tiles to not blow out memory).

But, the main problem here is WHILE scrolling AND adding/removing tiles (using addview() and removeView()) the scrolling is jerky. I have the same app in iOS, using the same approach and the scrolling is perfect.

Here's basically what I have:

```
// Main activity
RelativeLayout tileCanvas = new RelativeLayout(this);
tileCanvas.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(800, 10000));
ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this).
scroll.addView(tileCanvas);
setContentView(scroll);

...

private void addTile(TileInfo tileInfo) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this.getContext());
    image.setImageBitmap(tileInfo.mBitmap);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(tileInfo.mWidth, tileInfo.mHeight);
    params.leftMargin = tileInfo.mLeft;
    params.topMargin = tileInfo.mTop;
    tileCanvas.addView(image, params);

}
```

I checked that if I stop calling addTile() after sometime, the scroll works perfectly with the tiles that are currently added in the tileCanvas.

Comment: I am not sure but i think you can solve it using Handler Thread because it is the case related to UI and in Android we use Handler Thread for update UI....so in this way we can solve it...

Comment: I'm already using Handlers to update the UI. Actually, addTile is called in the UI thread, through the Handler.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issues in my project. Why are you using your own filing mechanism with GestureDetector? 
ScrollView already handles all of that. Solution i found, 
1.Try to reduce the **if()** conditions and unwanted **nesting if()** condition in your code.
2.Please write the optimistic code structure is the only way increase the scrollview speed without jerk. But you hesitate the above step,Scrollview are affected. 
Thank you.